# How to force install fastboot drivers in Windows 10?

Tags: fastboot, windows

I've found several articles and questions and pages walking you through manually installing fastboot drivers.  That's not working.  Not even when I disable driver verification.  Windows just refuses to use the drivers.  I've even tried right clicking on the inf file and clicking INSTALL.  It says it works, but fastboot can't see anything, and device manager gives the yellow exclamation mark, meaning it's not using the drivers.

How can I force install the Fastboot drivers from Google?

I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: Drivers on Windows that are assigned to the wrong driver or have a missing driver (yellow exclamation mark in device manager) are installed by opening the device manager, selecting the device in the device tree you want to change the driver, open the properties window and then assign a new driver. In this process you can select the inf file.